# How can I use a npm modules directly in my projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have never used `npm` before so I may not be asking the question how it should be asked but I could not find this information anywhere. Let's say I am interested in using [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical). The author asks me to install the module which I do by typing the following in command line.

```
npm install --save critical
```

I am lost after that. The author writes a bunch of lines but I have no idea where to put them.

```
var critical = require('critical');
```

and

```
critical.generate({
  inline: true,
  base: 'test/',
  src: 'index.html',
  dest: 'index-critical.html',
  width: 1300,
  height: 900
});
```

Where do I put this code and how do I run it. I tried creating a file called `criticaldemo.js` and put all this code there but running it through command line did nothing. TO run it through command line I used the following command:

```
$ criticalfile.js
```

Can anyone please help me understand how to use npm modules?

Comment: Did it print anything in console?

Comment: @zero298 The console just flashed. I could not see anything. I am not talking about this particular module. I am interested in learning how to use these modules in general. This one is just for reference. :)

Comment: Are you double clicking a .bat file or something?  Open an actual command prompt and run your script there.

Comment: My hunch is that it would be most easily utilized in a build too like [GulpJS](http://gulpjs.com/) -- the documentation says it can be used without a plug-in with Gulp.

Comment: What about `node criticalfile.js`?

Comment: @zero298 Once I was in the project directory, I typed `criticalfile.js` and the console flashed once but I could not see anything.

Comment: Please read any [introduction to Node.js](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs) article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your project directory structure looks like:

```
project
  criticaldemo.js
```

You should navigate to `project` and run

```
npm init
```

This will create `package.json` inside your project. You can just press enter for each question to use the default values.

If you prefer, you can also manually create `package.json` based on the [requirements](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#requirements).

Here's how it should look, as a bare minimum (must have at least a `name` and `version`):

```
{
  "name": "my-cool-project",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Either way, at this point your directory should look like:

```
project
  criticaldemo.js
  package.json
```

Next, you run:

```
npm install --save critical
```

This will create a directory `node_modules` with your package inside of it:

Directory structure:

```
project
  criticaldemo.js
  package.json
  node_modules
```

Now inside your `criticaldemo.js`, you put the code as the package author said:

```
var critical = require('critical'); // this loads the package from node_modules/critical

critical.generate({
  inline: true,
  base: 'test/',
  src: 'index.html',
  dest: 'index-critical.html',
  width: 1300,
  height: 900
});
```

Finally you run the program using node:

```
node criticaldemo.js
```

Comment: Thank you very much nemo035. I have just one more question, what is the proper name for these packages? I mean are they modules or packages? Is their proper name 'node modules'?

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure what you mean about the "proper name"? They are both packages and modules. They are stored as packages on `npm`, but they are used like `modules` in your code, since they are independent units of code like modules. There is not proper name though, they are both.